# How to recursively remove a character from a string?

Tags: java, recursion

How do I remove a target character from string using RECURSION?

I know it begins like:

```
public static String removeChar(String str, char target) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return str;
    } else {
        if (str.charAt(0) == target) {
            return removeChar(/*what goes in here?*/)
        }
        return removeChar(/*what goes in here?*/)
    }
}
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that if the first character is equal to the `target` character, you simply return the result of `removeChar()` applied on the rest of the `String` (i.e. the `String` without the first character), which removes the first character.

On the other hand, if the first character is not equal to the `target` character, you return a `String` starting with the original first character and ending with the result of applying `removeChar()` on the rest of the `String`.

```
public static String removeChar(String str, char target) {
    if(str.length() == 0) {
        return str;
    } else {
        if(str.charAt(0) == target) {
            // remote the first character, and apply the recursive method to
            // the rest of the String
            return removeChar(str.substring(1),target);
        } else {
            // don't remote the first character, and apply the recursive method to
            // the rest of the String
            return str.charAt(0) + removeChar(str.substring(1),target);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code inside the else-block:

```
if(str.charAt(0) == target) {
    return removeChar(str.substring(1), target);
}
return charAt(0) + removeChar(str.substring(1), target);
```

But I don't see a need to use recursion here, you could just use

```
str.replace(target, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You check the index of the 1st occurrence of the char and remove it from that position:

```
public static String removeChar(String str, char target) {
    int index = str.indexOf(target);
    if (index < 0)
        return str;
    else {
        return removeChar(str.substring(0, index) + str.substring(index + 1), target);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "0123045607890";
    System.out.println(removeChar(str, '0'));
}
```

will print:

```
123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution.

```
function isLetter(str) {
    return str.length === 1 && str.match(/[A-Z]/i);
}

function removeLetters(str) {
    //console.log(str);
    let val = str.substr(0, 1);
    console.log(val);
    if (isLetter(val)) {
        return removeLetters(str.substr(1))
    } else {
        console.log("Return", str);
        return str;
    }
}
```